# TypeError: train() got an unexpected keyword argument 'runs'

Tags: python, pyspark

for i in range(1,5):

```
      clusters=KMeans.train(params_only,i,maxIterations=100,runs=100,initializationMode="random")

      WSSSE=(params_only.map(lambda point: error(point)).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y))
      print("With"+str(i)+"cluster : Within set sum of squared error= " +str(WSSSE))
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>          1 for i in range(1,5):
>
> ----> 2     clusters=KMeans.train(params_only,i,maxIterations=100,runs=100,initializationMode="random")
>          3     WSSSE=(params_only.map(lambda point: error(point)).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y))
>          4     print("With"+str(i)+"cluster : Within set sum of squared error= " +str(WSSSE))
>
> TypeError: train() got an unexpected keyword argument 'runs'

I am getting this error while executing the code in Jupyter notebook and I have also imported these libraries

```
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans,KMeansModel

from numpy import array

from math import sqrt
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Properly format your code please

Comment: You give keyword argument runs to KMeans.train method. According to error message it shouldn't be there. Look at documentation for correct argumetns and if you can't find documents you can always try `help(KMeans.train)` in Python console.

Answer (score 1):

I have
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-clustering.html
Note: In MLLib of Spark 2.2.0, the parameter runs is removed.